# how to display share button in bigcommerce quickview popup

Tags: bigcommerce

how can I show share button in bigcommerce quickview popup.I have used `%%GLOBAL_QuickViewShareLinks%%` variable.but no use.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the theme, the share options should be there anyway. You shouldn't need to customize them. Make sure you aren't running something like uBlock as that can prevent them from showing.

Alternatively, you can use [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) to implement them yourself.

Comment: i have added AddThis code still i cant see share buttons

Comment: do you have an ad blocker program?

Comment: yes its working now.js file for addthis was not appending.thanks a lot